# How can I sort a nested collection using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I am fairly certain this is possible, but I am having some problems getting it to work. I am trying to get a simple object graph with only 1 level of nesting using linq. Here is an example of the structure:

```
public class City
{
 public int CityId { get; set; } 
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public List<House> Houses { get; set; }
}

public class House
{
 public int HouseId { get; set; }
 public int Number { get; set; }
 public int CityId { get; set; }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is get all the cities, with all of their related Houses. I am trying to have the cities sorted by Name, and then their nested houses sorted by number. I tried a projection, a foreach to sort, and a slow iteration after the query is complete. Here is the basics of what I have at the moment, but I cannot see how to access the nested set:

```
List<City> Cities = db.Cities.Include(c => c.Houses).OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

How can I also manage to sort each cities `Houses` by their `Number` (without affecting the order that the cities are in)?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/02/25/tip-1-sorting-relationships-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Would something like this work?

```
var Cities = 
           (from c in db.Cities
           orderby c.Name
           select new
           {
               Name = c.Name,
               Houses = c.Houses.OrderBy(c => c.Number).ToList()
           }
          );
```

Comment: Maybe name rename the second property in the anonymous type to Houses?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    var cities = (from city in db.Cities
                  orderby city.Name
                  select new {
                      City = city, 
                      Houses = city.Houses.OrderBy(c => c.Number)
                  })
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. There is no joining of _house.CityId == city.CityId_.

Comment: It orders by the result set by `city.Name`, then by `house.Number`

Comment: Only selecting the city doesn't net you the houses in the order you want.

Comment: But then, the ordering on _house.Number_ is lost because you don't use the value of _house_.

Comment: Thanks. I was just returning a `List<City>` as in the original post. Fixed, but now it's almost identical to @abe-meissler's answer.

Comment: If you're using entity framework (or something similar) you don't need to do any explicit joins. `city.Houses` is the set of `House` entities where `house.CityId == city.CityId`.